# PowerShell printing event not being triggered

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

Thanks in advance for any help.
I'm trying to use PowerShell V5 to generate an event in which I can trigger an action. In the example, I'm just trying to write-output as my action. When I print, the event isn't triggered though. What am I missing?

```
$print = new-object system.drawing.printing.printdocument
register-objectevent -inputobject $print -eventname beginprint -sourceidentifier print.beginprint -Action { write-output "Event triggered" }
```

Get-job shows the job in a 'Not Started' state.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the above to trigger a print job. Went down the path of using register-cimindication event.

To check the event log for a print, see: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/4ae9aee9-44e1-445e-a3c3-77a32f6d2318/getciminstance-not-finding-all-event-logs-in-win32ntlogevent?forum=ITCG as get-ciminstance/WMI doesn't browse that Event Log until you add an entry into the registry. Thanks jrv from the link for helping.